# Understanding the Surviving Generations Metric

Tags: java, netbeans, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, visualvm

Netbeans' memory monitoring tool (which is the same tool as VisualVm) has an interesting metric for tracking memory leaks : the Surviving Generations Metric.

A [definition of this metric](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/what_do_the_surviving_generations) can be found on oracle.com :

- a Generation is a set of instances created within the same GC interval (between two garbage collections)
- a Surviving Generation is a Generation that survives at least one garbage collection. The number of survived garbage collections - the generation's age - is its unique identifier
- Surviving Generations (metrics) value is the number of different Surviving Generations that are currently alive on the heap (number of Generations with different generation ages)

I have a question about the second definition. I know what it means for an **instance** to survive a garbage collection. But I'm not sure what it means for a **generation** to survive a garbage collection. Does it mean that *at least one* instance of the generation survives the garbage collection ?

Comment: Small correction: Netbeans' memory monitoring tool is not an embedded VisualVM. VisualVM contains stripped down version of NetBeans Profiler. CPU and Memory profiling in VisualVM is based on NetBeans Profiler code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Basically that means, that among the instances, that were created between garbage collection X and X+1, there are some, that are alive now, when more garbage collections have occurred.

In my opinion, all three definitions make sense only per class. I mean, "Surviving Generations (metrics) value" of the given class is the number of different Generations of this class that are now alive on the heap.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out that NetBeans/VisualVM is able to give this metric per class. And it is indeed a very useful information for tracking memory leaks !